# Adding HDF data to a mosaic dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset, hdf5

I am trying to add a couple of HDF rasters into a mosaic dataset, however no matter what I do I keep getting this error:

[image: HDF_mosaicDataset]

This is a screenshot of my inputs:

[image: inputs]

The raster processing and mosaic post-processing default options were left.

Any idea what the problems is?  Is there something that needs to be done with the .H5 files before adding them into the mosaic dataset??